# Converting text million value into number - power bi

Tags: powerbi, number-formatting, numeric

I did a few steps in Power BI. I have annual revenue column with high values as 600000000 and more..so I converted this column with number values into new column with million values:

1. I created new column annual revenue in millions using formula: `AnnualRevenue(Millions) = format('Reporting HubSpotCompanyCurrentValueView'[annualrevenue],  "#,0,,")` so I got values like: 1, 10, 716 etc. but all these values are text values not number so my question here how is it possible to convert into numeric values? I need to numeric value as I want to create range based on annual revenue and count values in specific range. When I'm trying to convert new column with million values I got error that it's not possible. Anyone can help me?

| annual revenue | annual_revenue(millions) |
| --- | --- |
| 100000000 | 100 |
| 2879430000 | 2879,43 |

Comment: Where is your sample data?

Comment: Looks like you're already struggling with markdown ...

Comment: @Peter I changed

Comment: Use a custom format for the column instead of a formula that returns a text string.  You can apply a custom format in [the Model view.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-modeling-view)

Comment: use    #,##,,.0M in the format...

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are using different terms for the same thing:

1. "annual revenue" vs. "annualrevenue"
2. "annual_revenue(millions)" vs. "AnnualRevenue(Millions)"

In Power BI this would cause problems.

To convert your annual revenue to a number of multiples of millions you could use either expression:

```
Annual Revenue (Millions) as Number = 'Table'[annual revenue] / 1e6

Annual Revenue (Millions) as Number = VALUE('Table'[annual_revenue(millions)])
```